# Querying Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three tables.

- Categories
- Products
- Brands

I have a relation on my categories table to the products like so:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','product_sub_categories','subcategory_id','product_id');
}
```

I have a relation on my Products table to the brands like so:

```
public function manuf()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand','brand');
    }
```

I'm querying the categories table to return products of that category by a certain brand.

**For example.**

I wan to see all products in Cars category with the brand Fiat.

I've tried the following but I feel Im missing something..

```
 $search = 'fiat';
 $products = $category->products()->where(function($query) use ($search){
                    $query->brand->name = $search;
                })->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

> to return products of that category by a certain brand

I assume that you know brand ID and category ID and that products and categories have many to many relationship (since you're using `belongsToMany`) and product belongs to brand:

```
Product::where('brand_id', $brandId)
       ->whereHas('categories', function($q) use(categoryId) {
           $q->where('id', $categoryId);
       })
       ->get();
```

Comment: Problem I've got with that is my products are related to many categories and defined by a products_categories associations table - would it still work?

Comment: @Dev.Wol yes, it'll work if both relations were defined correctly.